# how to install OpenJDK on Ubuntu 10.04 when sun-java6-jdk is already installed?

Tags: ubuntu, java

I'v installed sun-java6-jdk on Ubuntu 10.04. But, there a software only support OpenJDK. Can I install OpenJDK on Ubuntu 10.04 when sun-java6-jdk is already installed?

Comment: I can understand multiple JREs, but why the interest in installing multiple JDKs?

Comment: Looks like @felix has got a software requiring OpenJDK. I wonder what would that be and why.

Comment: Did you know we have our own Ubuntu-specific forums? askubuntu.com is the best place for Ubuntu questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can then use `update-alternatives` to switch between Java packages when more than one is installed.